# how to refresh jquery carousel autoplay

Tags: jquery, carousel

i need to refresh `div` or jQuery function after selecting a carousel from multiple instances from list on left when page loads it scrolls left but when function is executed the next scroller is stopped.

**The code is:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#carousel_1').carouFredSel({
      width: '100%',
      auto: {
        items: 1
      },
      prev: '#prev1',
      next: '#next1'
    });

    $('#carousel_2').carouFredSel({
      width: '100%',
      auto: {
        items: 1
      },
      prev: '#prev2',
      next: '#next2'
    });

    $('#carousel_3').carouFredSel({
      width: '100%',
      auto: {
        items: 1
      },
      prev: '#prev3',
      next: '#next3'
    });

    var items = $('.list_switch>li>a').each(function () {
      $(this).click(function () {
        //remove previous class and add it to clicked tab
        items.removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        //hide all content divs and show current one
        $('.carousel').hide().eq(items.index($(this))).show('fast');
      });
    });

    // select the first tab on page load       
    items[0].click();
  });
</script>
```

**The demo page:** http://blogillucent.alwaysdata.net/aaa/coolcarousel.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `play` event to resume the sliding on the selected slider:

**e.g.,**

```
$("#foo").trigger("play");
```

See the documentation [here](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/custom-events.php)!

**To your code in particular:**

```
var items = $('.list_switch>li>a').each(function () {
  $(this).click(function () {
    //remove previous class and add it to clicked tab
    items.removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    //hide all content divs and show current one
    $('.carousel').hide().eq(items.index($(this))).show('fast');

    // resume the slide on the selected slider
    $('.carousel').eq(items.index($(this))).trigger("play");
  });
});
```

By reading the documentation, it is supposed to pause the slider in order to use the `play` event, so you should after each slider initialization, pause the ones not visible:

**e.g.,**

```
$("#foo").trigger("pause");
```

---

You can take a look at the [Code examples for the custom events](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/code-examples/custom-events.php) for the `carouFredSel` plug-in!

Comment: @user743328 Glad I could help! :) Since the problem is solved, please tick the answer as correct to have this question _solved_!